# get latest date from each month and year in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe where I have the date and input column, and I want to take only the information of the latest date from each month and year.

The table looks like this

```
date        input
2017-04-06  0.036
2017-04-13  0.055
2017-04-20  0.07
2017-04-27  0.052
2017-05-04  0.039
2017-05-11  0.045
2017-05-18  0.033
2017-05-25  0.025
2017-06-01  0.018
2017-06-08  0.057
2017-06-15  0.05
2017-06-22  0.035
2017-06-29  0.038
```

the expected dataframe is:

```
date        input
2017-04-27  0.052
2017-05-25  0.025
2017-06-29  0.038
```

I have tried to use `.max()` but I only get the latest date of all date in the column, while I need to take all the columns from the latest date of each month and year.

How can I do this with python?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your case do `groupby` with `tail`

```
#df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
out = df.groupby(df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).tail(1)
Out[919]: 
         date  input
3  2017-04-27  0.052
7  2017-05-25  0.025
12 2017-06-29  0.038
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), as_index=False).last()
print (df)
        date  input
0 2017-04-27  0.052
1 2017-05-25  0.025
2 2017-06-29  0.038
```